Creating reactive rules for a vuetify form
I am struggling to get my vuetify form to function as intended. I was trying to get my form to validate once I hit submit without refreshing but also my two components one depends on the other. There is a select box and if one or the other entry is chosen from the list then the rules change for the file input to be only pdf and a singular entry. I am unsure how to get this to work as now the form does not validate based on those dynamic rules.
            <v-form ref="uploadForm" v-model="uploadDocumentValidation" @submit.prevent>
          <v-card-text>
            <div class="text-medium-emphasis mb-4">
              This operation will upload a doucument into ARMs.
            </div>

            <v-select
              v-model="uploadTypeModel"
              :items="cleanAllowableUploadTypes"
              item-title="name"
              label="File category uploading"
              :counter="300"
              class="mb-2 mt-5"
              variant="outlined"
              validate-on="submit"
              return-object
              :rules="objectRequiredRule"
            ></v-select>
            <v-file-input
                    v-model="filesToUploadModel"
                    :show-size="1000"
                    color="primary"
                    label="File(s)"
                    placeholder="Select your file(s)"
                    prepend-inner-icon="mdi-file"
                    prepend-icon=""
                    variant="outlined"
                    validate-on="submit"
                    counter
                    comfortable
                    :multiple="uploadTypeModel != null && (uploadTypeModel.name == 'Revised Certification' || uploadTypeModel.name == 'Addendum') ? false : true"
                    :rules="uploadTypeModel != null && (uploadTypeModel.name == 'Revised Certification' || uploadTypeModel.name == 'Addendum') ? certificationOrAddendumRule : arrayRequiredRule"
                    :accept="uploadTypeModel != null && (uploadTypeModel.name == 'Revised Certification' || uploadTypeModel.name == 'Addendum') ? '.pdf' : ''"
                  >
                    <template v-slot:selection="{ fileNames }">
                      <template v-for="(fileName) in fileNames" :key="fileName">
                        <v-chip
                          class="me-2"
                          color="blue-accent-4"
                          size="small"
                          label
                        >
                          {{ fileName }}
                        </v-chip>
                      </template>
                    </template>
                  </v-file-input>

            <div class="text-overline mb-2">HELPFUL INFORMATION</div>

            <div class="text-medium-emphasis mb-1">
              All files uploaded are stored in the cloud with redundant backups of each version.
            </div>
          </v-card-text>

          <v-divider class="mt-2"></v-divider>

          <v-card-actions class="my-2 d-flex justify-end">
            <v-btn
              class="text-none px-5"
              rounded="xl"
              text="Cancel"
              @click="isActive.value = false"
            ></v-btn>

            <v-btn
              class="text-none mr-3 my-3 px-5"
              color="primary"
              rounded="xl"
              text="Upload"
              variant="flat"
              @click="uploadFiles()"
              type="submit"
            ></v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>                        
        </v-form>

My script is as follows
      const certificationOrAddendumRule = [
  (v: any) => !!v || "File is required!",
  (v: any) => v.type != 'application/pdf' || "File must be a pdf!",
  (v: any) => !v.isArray || "Only one document allowed for this type of upload!"]

My validation function is as follows:
  const uploadFiles = () => {
uploadForm.value.validate().then(async (result: any) => {
  if(result.valid == true) {
    if(uploadDocumentValidation.value && certificationReviewModel.value != null)
    {
      loadingFileUpload.value = true
      switch (uploadTypeModel.value.name) {
        case 'Revised Certification':
          await documentStore.uploadRevisedCertification(certificationReviewModel.value!.mmcid,filesToUploadModel.value!)
          break;
        case 'Addendum':
          await documentStore.uploadAddendum(certificationReviewModel.value!.mmcid,filesToUploadModel.value!)
          break;
        case 'Supporting Document':
          await documentStore.uploadSupportingDocuments(certificationReviewModel.value!.mmcid,filesToUploadModel.value!)
          break;
        case 'Contract':
          await documentStore.uploadContractDocuments(certificationReviewModel.value!.mmcid,filesToUploadModel.value!)
          break;
        case 'ILOS Document':
          await documentStore.uploadIlosDocuments(certificationReviewModel.value!.mmcid,filesToUploadModel.value!)
          break;
        case 'Miscellaneous':
          await documentStore.uploadMiscellaneousDocuments(certificationReviewModel.value!.mmcid,filesToUploadModel.value!)
          break;
        case 'DMCP Working File':
          await documentStore.uploadDMCPWorkingDocuments(certificationReviewModel.value!.mmcid,filesToUploadModel.value!)
          break;
        default:
          console.log('error')
      }
      await certificationReviewStore.loadCertificationReview(certificationReviewModel.value!.mmcid)
      loadingFileUpload.value = false    
    }  
  }
})

}

Put your rules in the computed property.
Paste the code where you validate the form if it still doesn't help.
computed: {
  certificationOrAddendumRule() {
    return [
      (v: any) => !!v || "File is required!",
      (v: any) => v.type != 'application/pdf' || "File must be a pdf!",
      (v: any) => !v.isArray || "Only one document allowed for this type of upload!"
    ];
  }
}


I added the validation I use. I ended up having to use the promise system they implement but I thought this could all happen under the hood and update the v-form model automatically since I assume the props would make it reactive?

Using the rule as a computed property still doesnt do anything. It was worth a shot though.
